# Locations from Bim360 api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

Is there an exposed endpoint to get the locations that are associated with a project?

I'm using the bim360 checklist endpoint and getting a checklist that has a location Id I wist to get the information about that location so that I can place it in a report for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have endpoints. Here's the [Documentation Link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-GET/)

Comment: that only returns the ID of the location I want to get the actual location associated with the checklist from this ID.

Comment: We don't have a signed URL for resources that you can use for download.
You can implement that feature by downloading the information and send the response from your endpoint.